# Doing multiplication on my Rails App with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, math

I'm just starting to learn Rails so please forgive the dumb question. In my web app, I was able to set up a working model, form, and view. A user is able to input their decimal answer and it shows on the web page perfectly. However, I want to multiple whatever the user inputs by 10. So if the user inputs 2 I want it to show 20. Any help that you guys can give me would be so amazing. I have listed below all my relevant code. Thank you again :)

**Rails Controller**

```
class Ratings1sController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@ratings1 = Ratings1.create(params[:ratings1].permit(:content))
@ratings1.user_id = current_user.id
@ratings1.post_id = @post.id

if @ratings1.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
else
  render 'new'
end
  end
end
```

**Rails Model**

```
class Ratings1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**_Form.html**

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@post, @post.ratings1s.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :content %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming content is your rating that you wish to multiply simply do:

```
@ratings1 = Ratings1.create(params[:ratings1].permit(:content))
@ratings.content *= 10
```

Incidentally you are saving your Ratings1 model twice - once when creating it and then when you call save on it. It would be better to build it then save it - you may wish to add validation for presence of user for example at some point and then calling create would fail.

```
@ratings1 = Ratings1.build(params[:ratings1].permit(:content))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is amazing and definitely will remember the validation point :)